# Custom JaCoCo Gradle Plugin - exclude files in report

Tags: groovy, gradle-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I'm new to Gradle and Groovy.
I have something like this in my `build.gradle` file:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['aaa/bbb.*', 'ccc/ddd/*',])
        }))
    }
}
```

Now, I need this in my custom plugin. But I'm not sure how to set these excludes to it.
I have something like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate { p ->
    def reportTask = project.tasks.findByName('jacocoTestReport') as JacocoReport
    reportTask.classDirectories.setFrom(reportTask.classDirectories.files.) // Now what?
}
```

And I'm stuck here. Can you help me sort this out, please?

EDIT1:

I tried to solve it using patternSet.

```
println '----------------BEFORE REPORT----------------------'
def patternSet = new PatternSet()
def filesAsString = reportTask.classDirectories.files.collect { file ->
    file.path
}
patternSet.setIncludes(filesAsString)
patternSet.setExcludes(['aaa/bbb.*', 'ccc/ddd/*'])
def excludeFiles = reportTask.classDirectories.asFileTree.matching(patternSet).files
println filesAsString
println excludeFiles
def files = reportTask.classDirectories.asFileTree.minus(excludeFiles)
reportTask.classDirectories.setFrom(files)
println '----------------AFTER REPORT----------------------'
println reportTask.classDirectories.files
```

Result is not what I expected:

```
----------------BEFORE REPORT----------------------
[aaa\bbb\build\classes\java\main, aaa\bbb\build\classes\groovy\main, aaa\bbb\build\resources\main]
[]
----------------AFTER REPORT----------------------
[]
```

No exclude directories at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I somehow solved it.

```
def ex = ['aaa/bbb/*','ccc/ddd.*','eee/fff/*']
def ft = reportTask.classDirectories.asFileTree.matching {
    ex.each {
        exclude it
    }
}
```

Don't ask me how Gradle wraps this since it's not a Groovy syntax, but it works.
My opinion is that Gradle somehow implements `AntlrTask` as a pattern matcher since it implements interface 'PatternFilterable' and documentation mentions Ant. I tried to solve it in pure Groovy using `PatternSet` which is another class implementing `PatternFilterable` but I haven't succeded.

But the simple `exclude 'aaa/bbb/*'` works OK. It doesn't take list so I had to do it using `forEach` cycle. Maybe there is more simple and elegant way and I'll try to play with it but this solution is good enough.